# Navigating inside a function in react

Tags: reactjs, rest

I have a delete button present in the '/book' page. On clicking this button, it should delete the contents in the server(this works fine). But after deleting the records,page should refresh. But it's not happening.

```
<Button  onClick={(e) => { this.deleteRecord(e, k.id) }}>Delete</Button>
```

Here is the deleteRecord() function:

```
deleteBook(e, id) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(`url/${id}`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
    }).then(res => {
        return res.json()
    })
        .then(data => console.log(data))

        .catch(error => console.log('ERROR from delete component'))
    this.props.history.push('/book'); //to navigate
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For refresh a page, personally, I use that :

```js
window.location.reload(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Yes, it refreshed my page. Thank u..

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch(`url/${id}`, {
    method: 'DELETE',
}).then(res => {
    return res.json()
})
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .then(() => this.props.history.push('/book'); //to navigate)
    .catch(error => console.log('ERROR from delete component'))
```

You should put the router event inside the .then, 'cause the two functions are executing at the same time with no order.

The algoritm that you are pursuiting is: DELETE > Routing.
Without that you have no control of what is happening
 inside your block

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yeah, I have tried this code. But it's not navigating to '/book' .

Comment: Is it because my delete button is present in the same page?(localhost:3000/book)

Comment: Yes @user3359964, i think you will need to reaload the page instead of navigate in this case

Comment: Try out location.reload();